# python location on mac osx

Tags: python, macos

I'm a little confused with the python on osx. I do not know if the previous owner of the laptop has installed macpython using macport. And I remembered that osx has an builtin version of python. I tried using `type -a python` and the result returned

```
python is /usr/bin/python
python is /usr/local/bin/python
```

However running both python at these locations give me `[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin`. Do they both refer to the same builtin python mac provided?

I also read that installing macpython one would

```
     A MacPython 2.5 folder in your Applications folder. In here you
 find IDLE, the development environment that is a standard part of
 official Python distributions...
```

I looked at `Applications`, and theres a `MacPort` folder with `python2.6` and the mentioned stuff in it. But running IDLE, i find the same message as above.

Hmm I'm a little confused. Which is which?

Comment: Trivia: Previous owner? If you purchase a computer second hand, just reinstall the OS to clean all previous user files and apps.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)]` is the version of GCC that the Python(s) were built with, not the version of Python itself.  That information should be on the previous line.  For example:

```
# Apple-supplied Python 2.6 in OS X 10.6
$ /usr/bin/python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 

# python.org Python 2.7.2 (also built with newer gcc)
$ /usr/local/bin/python
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Items in `/usr/bin` should always be or link to files supplied by Apple in OS X, unless someone has been ill-advisedly changing things there.  To see exactly where the `/usr/local/bin/python` is linked to:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  68 Jul  5 10:05 /usr/local/bin/python@ -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

In this case, that is typical for a python.org installed Python instance or it could be one built from source.

Answer (score 135):

This one will **solve all your problems** not only on **Mac** but
to find it on **Linux** also ( & every basic shell).

**TL;DR** (you don't have to go through all the answer - just the 1st half).
LET'S GO

Run in terminal:

```
which python3
```

On Mac you should get:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

**WAIT!!!** It's prob a symbolic link, how do you know? Run:

```
ls -al /usr/local/bin/python3
```

and you'll get (if you've installed Python w/ Brew):

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 -> /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/bin/python3
```

which means that your

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

is actually pointing to (the **real** location)

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/bin/python3
```

**That's it!**

**Longer version (optional):**
If for some reason, your

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

is not pointing to the place you want, which is in our case:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/bin/python3
```

just back it up (+cool trick to add `.orig` suffix to file):

```
cp /usr/local/bin/python3{,.orig}
```

and run:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/python3
```

now create a new symbolic link:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python3
```

and now your

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

is pointing to

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/bin/python3
```

Check it out by running:

```
ls -al /usr/local/bin/python3
```

Comment: finally.... thank you!!!!! i was running into this issue in a virtual environment. Solutions also works. just need to use the correct python location

Comment: This is also a useful reference for me for basic shell itself - lots of incremental steps, and very well explained :)

Comment: In my case python3 wasn't a symlink and @MaPY's solution showed me the path as - <module 'posixpath' from '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/posixpath.py'>

Comment: On macOS Ventura/Sonoma Python is located here:
`/usr/bin/python3`
it is a direct binary file, not a symlink.

Answer (score 93):

I found the easiest way to locate it, you can use

`which python`

it will show something like this:

`/usr/bin/python`

Comment: This does not answer which distribution of Python (who made it).

Answer (score 64):

On Mac OS X, it's in the Python framework in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Resources`.

Full path is:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```

Btw it's easy to find out where you can find a specific binary: `which Python` will show you the path of your Python binary (which is probably the same as I posted above).

Comment: yea i knew that. Its just that I'm confused -  I ran the interpreter on /usr/local/bin/ and printed sys.executable. It says /usr/bin/python. but I read the docs and it says that the apple-provided was in /usr/bin/ and the macpython's "A symlink to the Python executable is placed in /usr/local/bin/".

Comment: Well, it makes sense: when you compile the python-executable yourself and move it to, say /Users/John/Downloads/, it'll show you it's placed at /Users/John/Downloads/python. You can run multiple executable next to each other on the same system. AFAIK the one in Python.framework is the primary one though, so you should rely on that one.

Comment: Actually, the Apple-supplied Pythons in Mac OS X are in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`.  Anything in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` comes from a third-party install, usually a python.org (or other distributor) installer or if you did a default framework build of Python from source.

Comment: When I run `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7` the `ps aux` output shows me `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`, why is that - I don't see that it's a symlink ? ( Asked this question at [AskDifferent](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126257/full-path-to-python-as-reported-by-ps) )

Comment: @Tim Thanks. When I go to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/, I see not 2.7 (which is what I have installed), but an alias file called 'Current', which, when clicked, gives me the error *"The operation can't be competed because the original item for 'Current' can't be found."*

Comment: Surprisingly `which python` shows `/usr/bin/pythin` which is not a symlink. It's a dead-end finding the location.

Answer (score 9):

I checked a few similar discussions and found out the best way to locate all python2/python3 builds is:

```
which -a python python3
```

Answer (score 8):

On High Sierra

```
which python
```

shows the default python but if you downloaded and installed the latest version from python.org you can find it by:

```
which python3.6
```

which on my machine shows

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6
```

Comment: This does not answer which distribution of Python (who made it).

Answer (score 5):

installed with 'brew install python3', found it here 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Run this in your interactive terminal

```
import os
os.path
```

It will give you the folder where python is installed

Answer (score 1):

`which python3` simply result in a path in which the interpreter settles down.

Answer (score 1):

run the following code in a .py file:

```
import sys

print(sys.version)
print(sys.executable)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a cook recipe for finding things in linux/macos

First update the locate db then do a

```
locate WHATiWANTtoSEARCH | less
```

do a /find to find what you are looking for.

to update your locate db in macos do this:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
```

it sometimes takes a while. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

i found it here: 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin

Comment: This is not Apple-native Python installation.

Answer (score -5):

Just simply run this. It would fix the error

`pip install -U pyopenssl`

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?