# Python 3 virtualenv problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I'm having a problem similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842713/using-python-3-in-virtualenv), but I am already running the latest version of `virtualenv` and I also get a different `ImportError`.

Using virtualenv with version 2.7 (default) works fine but I need to use python3 for another project.  I installed it using `brew install python3` in OSX 10.10.2.

When I try:

```
> pip install --upgrade virtualenv
Requirement already up-to-date: virtualenv in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...

> virtualenv --version
12.0.7

> virtualenv -p python3 test
```

I still get:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4'
New python executable in venv/bin/python3.4
Also creating executable in venv/bin/python
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/site.py", line 73, in <module>
    __boot()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/site.py", line 2, in __boot
    import sys, imp, os, os.path   
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/project/studyprocessor/venv/bin/../lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 22, in <module>
    from importlib import util
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/project/studyprocessor/venv/bin/../lib/python3.4/importlib/util.py", line 12, in <module>
    from contextlib import contextmanager
ImportError: No module named 'contextlib'
ERROR: The executable venv/bin/python3.4 is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/Users/user/Desktop/project/studyprocessor' (should be '/Users/user/Desktop/project/studyprocessor/venv')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pip` program what you are using corresponds to the Python 2.7 version. You need to use the `pip` which corresponds to Python 3.x. So, you should be using

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```

Alternatively, you can create virtual environments in Python 3.3+ with the [`venv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#module-venv), like this

```
python3 -m venv test
```

Comment: `pip3 install --upgrade virtualenv` gives me `Requirement already up-to-date: virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages`

Comment: @OpenUserX03 You might want to try the alternate option I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**try following**

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute -p /usr/bin/python3 ~/.virtualenvs/py3

workon py3
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct, please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.