# python3.7 virtual environment creation fails in debian 10 with AttributeError

Tags: python, debian, virtualenv, python-3.7

I'm using Debian 10 buster with `python3.4` as the default python version.

```
sridharrajs@debian:~/Desktop/repos/demo$ python3 --version
Python 3.4.2
```

For one of my new projects I want to use `python3.7`.

```
sridharrajs@debian:~/Desktop/repos/demo$ python3.7 --version
Python 3.7.3
```

When I create a virtual environment, it fails with `AttributeError: module 'posix' has no attribute '__all__'`

```
sridharrajs@debian:~/Desktop/repos/demo$ virtualenv -p python3.7 venv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3.7
Fatal Python error: initsite: Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 42, in _get_exports_list
    return list(module.__all__)
AttributeError: module 'posix' has no attribute '__all__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 79, in <module>
    import os
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 65, in <module>
    __all__.extend(_get_exports_list(posix))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 44, in _get_exports_list
    return [n for n in dir(module) if n[0] != '_']
SystemError: <built-in function dir> returned NULL without setting an error
```

I tried [Ubuntu 'Failed to import the site module' error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47444042/ubuntu-failed-to-import-the-site-module-error-message), [Python 3 virtualenv problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28923926/python-3-virtualenv-problems), [Using Python 3 in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842713/using-python-3-in-virtualenv?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Have a look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42214414/this-package-should-not-be-accessible-on-python-3-when-running-python3/42214539#42214539

Comment: How did you get python 3.4? Buster comes with 3.7 by default: https://packages.debian.org/buster/python3

Comment: @barti_ddu I was using debain 8 before upgrading, so got 3.4 as a part of that. When I upgraded to debian 10, got 3.7. But for some reason, 3.7 is not the default one.

Comment: IMHO, your python installation is a mess. **Make a system backup** and try upgrading python3 and virtualenv to relevant versions. Also ditch your local python3.7 installation (You seem to have python3.7 install at /usr/local).

Comment: try with `which python3.7` (to check it you have a local version), check with `apt` if the upgrade was not successful, and repair. Ev. reinstall python