# How to install virtualenv for python3?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am creating a Django App and stuck at virtualenv installation. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842713/using-python-3-in-virtualenv) and tried to follow but it resulted in this everytime I tried something. Why can't it take python 3 for installing but this works `virtualenv venv` but it installs for python 2. What should I do?

```
virtualenv -p python3 venv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /home/oroborus/anaconda3/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/home/oroborus/anaconda3'
New python executable in venv/bin/python3
Also creating executable in venv/bin/python
venv/bin/python3: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR: The executable venv/bin/python3 is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/home/oroborus/PycharmProjects/test-app' (should be '/home/oroborus/PycharmProjects/test-app/venv')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

Typing `locate libpython3.5`

```
locate libpython3.5
/home/oroborus/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/libpython3.5m.so
/home/oroborus/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/libpython3.5m.so.1.0
/home/oroborus/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m/libpython3.5m.a
/home/oroborus/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.5m.so
/home/oroborus/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.5m.so.1.0
/home/oroborus/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m/libpython3.5m.a
/home/oroborus/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.2-0/lib/libpython3.5m.so
/home/oroborus/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.2-0/lib/libpython3.5m.so.1.0
/home/oroborus/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.2-0/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m/libpython3.5m.a
```

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: have you installed python3 on your OS?

Comment: Yup it's there... `python --version` gives me this output
`Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In debian like distros `python3-venv` is available.

Install it using apt `sudo apt-get install python3 python3-venv`.

Then use it like that `python3 -m venv yourvenvfoldername`.

**EDIT**:

In this case anaconda is used, which has the replacement `conda` for both, pip and virtualenv. There is nice command comparison table available in the [docs](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/_downloads/conda-pip-virtualenv-translator.html).

Creating a virtualenv with conda can be done like that:

`conda create --name $ENVIRONMENT_NAME python`

Comment: Running this gave an output `python3 -m venv env
Error: Command '['/home/oroborus/PycharmProjects/test-app/env/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1`

Comment: might this be related http://askubuntu.com/questions/488529/pyvenv-3-4-error-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1 ?

Comment: forget about... this should be fixed in 15.04

Comment: based on the comments above i've notived that you use anaconda. i guess it has something to do with it.

Comment: anaconda has replacements for venv and pip as described [here](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/_downloads/conda-pip-virtualenv-translator.html)

Comment: The answer above only applies to python3 on debian based distros.

Comment: So instead of using `virtualenv` I can use `conda` do you mean to say probably with this card `conda create --name $ENVIRONMENT_NAME python`

Comment: It did.. Thanks.. Could you add that to the answer so I can mark it.. :D