# Understanding virtualenv in relation to python

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I'm having a difficult time wrapping my head around how to utilize [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) and python3 together. As I understand it, [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) acts as an operating system within my mac's operating system. I installed virtualenv through the terminal and can activate/deactivate it successfully, but how do I use python3 with it?

I understand the python shell, I understand the terminal, but after I created the `my_projects` directory for virtualenv, how can I ensure I'm creating something in a virtualenv with python?

I'm not using homebrew or anaconda.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Python 3 in virtualenv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842713/using-python-3-in-virtualenv)

Comment: "As I understand it, virtualenv acts as an operating system within my mac's operating system" No. It acts as an *environment* isolated from your working environment. A virtual environment, you might say...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the virtual environment will isolate from the OS python. You can create a virtual env per project.
For example project `projectA`, you can create an venv inside `projectA` as:

```
cd projectA
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.5 venv-name-A
```

When you install any packages for projectA, you do:
`/path/to/venv-name-A/bin/pip install <pkg-name>`

When you run your projectA, you do:
`/path/to/venv-name-A/bin/python projectA-file.py`

You can create as many venvs as you want. You can install any packages on any envs without breaking your OS python accidentally.

Comment: Thank you, Haifeng. I'm struggling now because the path that my project was installed looks a bit different than yours. My looks like: /Users/Main/Desktop/Python_practice/Lamba/myproject. From the myproject directory I entered virtualenv venv. Did I install the virtual environment in the wrong location initially?

Comment: @basiclanguage no matter where you store the venv, it is isolated from your OS python, and you know the installed packages are for the specific project:)

Comment: Okay cool, what would be the difference between these two: python3 -m pip install virtualenv & virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.5 venv-name-A ?

Comment: i think it should be  `pip install virtualenv`, in which installs virtulenv package. the latter command is  creating venv based on python3.5

Comment: This really clears it up for me, Haifeng. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

A Virtual Environment is a tool to keep the **dependencies required by different projects in separate places**, by creating virtual Python environments for them.

It solves the `“Project X depends on version 1.x but, Project Y needs 4.x”` dilemma, and keeps your global site-packages directory clean and manageable.

For example, you can work on a project which requires Django 1.10 while also maintaining a project which requires Django 1.8.

For more understanding refer to this [Python Guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).