# Python3 with virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am trying to set up a python3 virtualenv on my mac.

I type in my folder :

```
virtualenv -p python3
source bin/activate
```

And is says :

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3
```

However when I do `print(5/2)` it outputs `2`, which is python2. I conclude that my virtualenv isn't running on python3 but on python2. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842713/using-python-3-in-virtualenv