# how to install python packages in "site-packages"?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I made `Virt2` virtual environment.
using `$ python -m venv Virt2`.

I want to install my custom packages in "`site-packages`" directory. However packages are installed in "`dist-packages`" directory.

[image]

what should I do to install packages in my python virtual environment **site-packages**??

---

my python version 3.6.2 (in /usr/local/bin)

Comment: You are telling that your python version is 3.6 and the package is in 3.4.May be this is due to the different versions of python

Comment: why their version is not the same??
what should I do to enforce same version?

Comment: you should specify the Python version while creating your python environment.checkout answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842713/using-python-3-in-virtualenv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `sudo` and `sudo` switches user to `root`, i.e. you're completely outside of you virtual env. System `pip3` outside of virtual env installs packages into a system directory which is `dist-packages`.

Run `pip install` inside you virtual env without sudo.