# Syntax error in existing Django project

Tags: python, django, git

I've installed existing Django project very 1st time and I've the problem with starting servers `python manage.py runserver`

Here it's what I've done

1.Clone the repo,

2.Make a virtual environment

3.Pip install requirements.txt

4.Generate access token and secret key and put in secrets.sh. I've the same SECRET_KEY in `settings.py` and `secrets.sh` and I've added secrets.sh to `.gitignore`

5.Change `settings.py` as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'USER': 'name',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

And I cannot run `python manage.py migrate` results below:

```
(tag_gen) local_user@local_user:~/Repo/tag_gen/generator$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7febe4712488>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/local_user/Repo/tag_gen/tag_gen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/local_user/Repo/tag_gen/tag_gen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/local_user/Repo/tag_gen/tag_gen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/local_user/Repo/tag_gen/tag_gen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/local_user/Repo/tag_gen/tag_gen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/local_user/Repo/tag_gen/tag_gen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/local_user/Repo/tag_gen/tag_gen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/local_user/Repo/tag_gen/tag_gen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/local_user/Repo/tag_gen/tag_gen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/local_user/Repo/tag_gen/tag_gen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/local_user/Repo/tag_gen/tag_gen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/local_user/Repo/tag_gen/tag_gen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/local_user/Repo/tag_gen/generator/generator/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    url(r'^etg/', include('generatorApp.urls', namespace='generatorApp')),
  File "/home/local_user/Repo/tag_gen/tag_gen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/local_user/Repo/tag_gen/generator/generatorApp/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/local_user/Repo/tag_gen/generator/generatorApp/views.py", line 170
    def view_index(request: WSGIRequest):
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Ideas?

Comment: When using sqlite3 you can scrap all fields in `DATABASES['default']` but `ENGINE` and `NAME`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The project you're trying to run is using Python ≥ 3.5, but you're trying to run it in 2.7.

The syntax `(request: WSGIRequest):` is a *type hint*. It was introduced [a few years ago](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), but was only added to the newer versions of Python 3. No effort was made to support Python ≤ 3.4.

You'll need to look up instructions on how to create a `virtualenv` with a high enough version of Python. This changes based on operating system, so verbose instructions are probably out of scope for this question, [but there is plenty of advice on the topic already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842713/using-python-3-in-virtualenv).

Comment: Yup, you're right. I've prepared new venv and works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1.Check python and django versions you have should be compatible with the installed requirements.
if you have python version more than 3.+ run server with

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

else if python version 2.7+

```
python manage.py runserver
```