# Change the python2.7 package to my required python3.5 package when use virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

When I create the virtualenv, if I do not add the `--no-site-packages` as param:

```
virtualenv venv
```

I can get the packages, in the

`venv/lib/`

there are a `python2.7` package:

```
python2.7
```

under the `python2.7` there are site-packages.

But, I have a requirement, I want copy the `python3.5` to the `venv/lib/` how can I do this?

---

**EDIT-1**

I use the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842713/using-python-3-in-virtualenv) method create the `venv`, in the `venv/lib/`:

there is the `python3.5` directory, but in the `venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages` there are few packages:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

But in my Mac's sitepages:

there are so many packages, my requirement is add those packages in the `venv` when create the `venv`:

my origin site-packages path is:`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages`

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

**EIDT-2**

Before, I do not use virtualenv, I have installed many site-packages in my Mac, (`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages`), and I want to use `venv` now, so I am looking for a method to create the `venv` and the site-packages I have installed should include in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Python 3 in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842713/using-python-3-in-virtualenv)

Comment: @waLLe Hi, friend, see my post, my requirement is add the site-packages to the new created `venv`, but I use the accepted and high upvoted answer, there do not get the effect.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should install `virtualenv` using python3.5. 
there is a tricky way that I use, I add some lines to the `.bashrc` file like this:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3.5
alias v.activate="source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh"
```

so whenever I want to change my `virtualenv` to be on python3.5 I run the `v.activate` command, and then create my virtual environment with python3.5.

remember this that:

> 1.I use `virtualenvwrapper` instead of `virtualenv`
>
> 2.Dont forget to run `source .bashrc` after you add those lines to `bashrc`

Comment: Do you know my requirement?  I want when create the `venv` I add the packages of `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages` to it.

Comment: You want to transfer the packages from python2.7 to 3.5 ?

Comment: No, before I do not use virtualenv, I have installed many site-packages in my Mac, (`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages`), and I want to use `venv` now, so I am looking for a method to create the `venv` and the site-packages I have installed should include in it.

Comment: so install them again after you activate the virtual environment. whats the problem ? the versions ?

Comment: I mean, whether there is a way I do not need install in the virtual enviroment.