# How to change python version in command prompt if I have 2 python version installed

Tags: python

I have installed `Anaconda 2 & 3` in my system. `Anaconda 2` contains `python 2.7` & `Anaconda 3` contains `python 3.6`.

I need to run my python code using command prompt & I need to use python 3.6
While I'm running `python --version`, I'm getting `python 2.7.14`. How do I change it to python 3.6?

Comment: Just specify the path to the executable you want to use. If you're on Linux I think there is the `which` command at your disposal?

Comment: try python3 --version

Comment: The best way to control the complete python environment is by using virtualenv. The rest is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842713/using-python-3-in-virtualenv

Comment: Run `$ python3`. This should open a python3 interactive prompt.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[image: Both Python2 and Python3 is installed]
As you can see, I have both Python2 and Python3 installed.

[image: Windows Path variable]
I hope you know that the path of the python executable has to be added to the PATH environment variable in Windows. As you can see, the path of Python2 is placed above the path of Python3 in my system.

**How does the cmd run commands?**
It searches for an executable with the same name in the directory the cmd has been opened in, then goes and searches for the command in the locations provided in the Windows PATH variable, from TOP to BOTTOM.
Which means, it gets the path to Python2 before it can get to the path of Python3. Therefore, every time you type `python` in your cmd, it runs Python2.
Both Python2 and Python3 executables have the same name in Windows so it never runs python3.

**What seems like an obvious solution?**
You might think, changing the name of `python.exe` to `python3.exe` for the Python3 executable will solve your problem. You are partially right, it will work. But you have to use `python3 file.py` or `python3 --version`, which I think, is understandable. But, pip will no longer work if you change the name of the original python executable. You will no longer be able to install external packages and modules.

**How can this problem be solved?**
You can create an alias for the Python3 executable called `python3.bat`.
`.exe` and `.bat` files can be called from the cmd directly without using their extension. We always write `python filename.py` instead of `python.exe filename.py` although both are correct. The same can be done with `.bat` files.
Go back to the first image and notice the `python3.bat` file below `python.exe`. That is my way of calling python3 without renaming my original python executable.

**python3.bat**
Create a new file using notepad or something and paste this `%~dp0python %*`
I don't fully understand how this works except that `dp0` basically runs python from inside the same directory and `%*` passes all the arguments to the python executable. Place this file inside your Python3 installation directory and your problem will hopefully be solved.

[image: Python and Python3]
python3 basically runs your `python3.bat` file, which in turn runs the `python.exe` from its folder and passes the arguments to it.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I was once searching for this problem and i couldnt find a viable solution. This is a very good workaround.

Comment: This works but seems a bit hacky for such a simple and common thing. As of now is this the recommended way of doing?

Comment: @LudovicBeghin I agree that it's too much work for something so simple. However, there are other tools like virtualenv, conda, pyenv etc that will let you manage multiple versions of python. Ideally, you should be having separate environments for separate projects. But if this solution solves your use case just go ahead and use it!

Answer (score 6):

You should have `python3` also in your path. You could use `python3` to run your script:

```
python3 <your_script>
```

But to answer your question, you could use `alias` and update it as `python`.

```
$ python --version    
Python 2.7.6
$ alias python=python3
$ python --version    
Python 3.6.4
```

Comment: While this answer is correct, I think it would be better to directly run `python3` instead of creating an alias. If the user will want `python2` at some future time, he/she can directly run `python` (which was the default behavior).

Comment: hence, the first part of answer. :)

Comment: @akshat quick question, when I do this it does not seem to "save it", when I close the terminal window and do python --version again, it displays the previous version

Comment: @ArthurLanglois, you can add it to your ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run Python 3.6, then execute `python3.6`. 
Otherwise, check with `which python` where the symbolic link to the actual python executable is. On my system, it's

```
/usr/bin/python
```

and when I `ls -la /usr/bin/python`, it gives

```
lrwxrwxrwx 42 user user 42 Aug 24 03:45 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
```

If you are really sure that you want to do it, you can now just move the old symlink somewhere:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/old_python
```

and create a new symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python
```

Now you should get something like:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.5
```

I don't guarantee that it doesn't break everything in the world, especially if you have some distro that has a package manager that relies on a specific python version under `python`.

This seemed to work nicely on Linux Mint 18.

Answer (score 1):

I made a small trick to solve this problem. For me

> C:\Python27

and

> C:\Python27\Scripts

were at the top of the PATH Environment variable list. I simply selected them and clicked on **Moved Down** to shift them to the end of the list.

> #### Just make sure that your path of Python3 and its Script folder is above Python2 path.

And it solved the problem for me. Hope it would help you too.

Reason :

> How does the cmd run commands?
>
> It searches for an executable with the same name in the directory the cmd has been opened in, then goes and searches for the command in the locations provided in the Windows PATH variable, from TOP to BOTTOM. Which means, it gets the path to Python2 before it can get to the path of Python3. Therefore, every time you type python in your cmd, it runs Python2.
> Both Python2 and Python3 executables have the same name in Windows so it never runs python3.

reason is taken from the accepted answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

- If Anaconda 3's is the only python3 interpreter in the system you can run `python3` instead of `python` in your command line and it should work.
- You can alter `PATH` parameter inverting the positions of both interpreters.

Answer (score -1):

In order to run your script with python 3 you can use

```
python3 <path to file>
```

P.S.: this should be a comment, but I do not have the required reputation. :)

Comment: No, this is good here. But it does not exactly answer the question. i.e. _How do I change it to python 3.6_

Comment: Upsy daisy, seeing your answer I realized that you are right, this is more an workaround, but it still works.

Answer (score -1):

I have two versions of the python which the first path is python 2(I am still working with python 2), but there are some scripts which should use python 3. This is what I have done:
I have create a bat file.
ex:
open Notepad++ and write :

```
@echo off
set PYTHONPATH=
"%~dpn0.py" %*
```

save it as 'yourscriptname.cmd'.
before my script(which should use python3) I just run this file in command line and then run my script. it is working.