# How can I change my version of Python to a prior version using Anaconda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I have Python 3.8.5 installed via Anaconda, but I want to switch it to Python 3.7.6. I tried to use `conda install python=3.7.6`, but after the command finished, I still get Python 3.8.5.

Comment: you can create new env with python=3.7.6

Comment: Try using pyenv to manage python versions. Conda is mainly used for dependencies and environments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have python version 3.7.6 installed on your system. Check this thread
[Change Python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50348975/how-to-change-python-version-in-command-prompt-if-i-have-2-python-version-instal/50349883)

And if you do not have the version you can download from [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and then try the above thread

Answer (score 0):

I use "conda install python=3.7 anaconda=custom" and it works.