# Running python3 and virtualenv in Google Cloud Instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, virtualenv

Within the Google Cloud Instance SSH console (running Debian), I installed Flask using pip.

Running `python3 demo.py` from the console or `demo.py` from the python3 interpreter (3.5.3) brings up `ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask'`.

Running `sudo apt-get install python3-venv` appears to successfully install and set up venv for python 3.5. But when attempting to create a virtualenv based on the [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/installation/):

```
$ python3 -m venv venv
/usr/bin/python3: No module named venv
```

Attempting `sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv` results in:

```
dpkg: error processing package virtualenv (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-virtualenv
 virtualenv
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Other unsuccessful suggestions include:

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
-bash: venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

and:

```
$ sudo virtualenv venv
New python executable in /home/user/demo/venv/bin/python
ERROR: The executable /home/user/demo/venv/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is u'/usr' (should be u'/home/user/demo/venv')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

Using python -V confirms that the python version is 2.7 in the console. For fun, running `python demo.py` returns

```
ImportError: cannot import name zip_longest
```

Following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842713/using-python-3-in-virtualenv?rq=1), I tried `pip install --upgrade virtualenv` resulting in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
    vendored("distro")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py", line 1051, in 
<module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py", line 595, in _
_init__
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py", line 934, in _
get_lsb_release_info
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lsb_release -a' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Am I missing something? Is this an issue with Google Cloud Console? Is there a workaround?

Comment: did you create a project folder and a venv folder in it?

Comment: also can you write python3 --version on the terminal to see if python3 is installed?

Comment: `$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.5`

Comment: Project folder was created. It's set up as a virtualenv inside this folder.

Comment: SUCCESS! Switching to venv from virtualenv, and then running it as `python3 demo.py` got it working. Thanks @WaleedIqbal!