# How to create virtual environment for python 3.7.0?

Tags: linux, virtualenv, python-3.7

I'm able to install it with root user but I wanted to install it in a clean environment. My use case is to test the installation of another application with pip for the customer who is using python3.7.0

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install build-essential libpq-dev libssl-dev openssl libffi-dev zlib1g-dev
>
> sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-dev
>
> sudo apt-get install python3.7

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to test on a complete new environment, you can use docker with appropriate python version inside (also useful if you want to run it on CI). Otherwise just use virtualenv, there are a lot of tutorials, just search for them

Comment: @soon thanks I'll try this option

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Python 3 in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842713/using-python-3-in-virtualenv)

Comment: pip3 installed python 3.5.x

Answer (score 57, accepted):

(assuming `python3.7` is installed)

Install `virtualenv` package:

```
pip3.7 install virtualenv
```

Create new environment:

```
python3.7 -m virtualenv MyEnv
```

Activate environment:

```
source MyEnv/bin/activate
```

Comment: before doing this you must have python 3.7 installed? is that correct?

Comment: @Boosted_d16 yes, exactly

Answer (score 39):

To help anyone else who runs into the chicken & egg situation trying to use the above chosen answer, here's what solved it for me:

```
sudo apt install python3.7-venv
python3.7 -m venv env37
source env37/bin/activate
deactivate (when done using the environment)
```

I had installed python 3.7 using deadsnakes vs source:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt install python3.7
```

In doing so I could run python3.7 --version but since I had no pip3.7 I could not install virtualenv as directed in the solution above. Luck would have it that deadsnakes has venv! Once I installed venv I could create my environment & be on my merry way

[Handy official python page with venv info](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)

So why didn't I use?:
    python3.7 -m ensurepip

That was giving me:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/easy_install.py'
>   Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Which left me with 3 choices:

> use sudo (which is simple but I keep being told is frowned upon)
>   install with --user option which wasn't ideal in that I may not always be logged in as the same user
>   or install it in an environment which I'm told is the recommended route.

But see chicken egg above.. How do I install pip in environment when I can't create venv or virtualenv?  Thus my workaround solution of installing venv from deadsnakes which allowed me to create the virtual environment to then install pip3.7:

```
(env37) user@ubuntu:~$ python3.7 -m ensurepip
(env37) user@ubuntu:~$ pip3.7 --version
pip 19.2.3 from /home/user/env37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using pip on windows, you can do the following:

1.`virtualenv --python "C:\\Python37\\python.exe" venv`# use your own path

You will see something like this:

Running virtualenv with interpreter C:\Python37\python.exe
Using base prefix 'C:\Python37'
New python executable in C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\GitHub\MyProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.

2.`C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GitHub\MyProject>cd venv
  C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GitHub\MyProject\venv>cd Scripts
  C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\GitHub\MyProject\venv\Scripts>activate`.

At the beginning of the command path, when you see (environment variable name) in this case (venv), this is a sign that your virtual environment is activated. 
`(venv) C:\Users\tuscar2001\Documents\GitHub\MyProject\venv\Scripts>`

Please check the following link for more details:http://www.datasciencetopics.com/2020/03/how-to-set-up-virtual-environment-in.html

Answer (score 3):

Some added information, if you are trying for some version like python 3.7.10, which might give following error upon executing `pip3.7.10 install virtualenv`

`.pyenv/versions/3.7.10/bin/python: No module named virtualenv`

So, in a general sense you can do the following steps:
[commands are specific to MacOs, I am currently using with the new M1 chip]

1. After installing 3.7.10 using pyenv, make it global.

```
brew update
brew install pyenv
```

set environment variables

```
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

look at the pyenv list to see if the version you install is there or not and install and make it global

```
pyenv install --list
pyenv install 3.7.10
pyenv global 3.7.10
```

2. create your virtual environment now with this version

```
python -m venv MyEnv
```

3. activate it

```
source MyEnv/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering here because none of the answers give you where to find python executable.

**Here's how to create a virtual environment with Python 3.7.9 on *Windows***

Go to the python version download page (with binary installers) https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-379/

[image: Python version download page]

Go to that page and download `Windows x86-64 embeddable` zip file
Then extract the zip file and place the contents inside the project folder (under `pthon379` folder).

Then use,

```
virtualenv --python .\python379\python.exe env
```

To create the virtual environment by specifying the exe location.

Now activate it using `.\env\Scripts\activate`

> If you get any error like virtualenv: The term 'virtualenv' is not
> recognized as a name of a cmdlet, uninstall virtualenv using pip
> uninstall virtualenv, close the terminal, open terminal as
> Administrator / root user and install again.

Answer (score 1):

Figure out python3.7 path on your system. For mac with python3.7 in brew you can use the following

```
virtualenv env -p /usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin/python3
source ./env/bin/activate
```