# Python venv (virual environment) uses wrong version of Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I have both Python 3.7 and 3.6 installed. But in my profile I set to use 3.6 and this is indeed a version that gets reported by `which python3`.

`$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3`

I then create virtual env by running `python3 -m venv venv`

And everything in my venv gets linked to the 3.6. I confirm this with `ls -la venv/bin` and by inspecting `venv/pyvenv.cfg`.

I activate the *venv* virtual environment.

I then install a *zappa* library with `pip install zappa`.

And when I run `zappa deploy`, I get an error that Python 3.7 is not supported. Why would a library use the version of Python that is not configured within the virtualenv and how do I make it use the correct version?

```
(venv) $ zappa deploy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/t/Projects/djzappa/Spheres/venv/bin/zappa", line 7, in <module>
    from zappa.cli import handle
  File "/Users/t/Projects/djzappa/Spheres/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zappa/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError(err_msg)
RuntimeError: This version of Python (3.7) is not supported!
Zappa (and AWS Lambda) support the following versions of Python: ['2.7', '3.6']
```

**NOTE**: I do NOT use virtualenv as everybody is suggesting, and as other existing answers are referring.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Python 3 in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842713/using-python-3-in-virtualenv)

Comment: No it is not a duplicate.

Comment: use pip3 install zappa, pip may well point to the 3.7 version.

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate actually. - The answer you marked as the answer, can be found in the one I marked.

Comment: Which one? Because I can't find a single one explaining the sequence of installations of different versions of Python - which is what solved MY problem. Including the comment discussion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this when you create environment:

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.6
```

But if you want to use venv, first of all, check whether `python3` in your terminal refers to the `python3.6` as you want.

If not - run your command with the full path to python3.6 instead of sole `python3` in `python3 -m venv venv`.

Edit: why your alias python3 is referring to python3.7 - it probably depends on OS you use and sequence of installation. Hard to say.

Comment: I don't use virtualenv. I use 'python3 -m venv'.

Comment: Try using /usr/bin/python36 -m venv; If it does not works either, please install virtualenv.

Comment: $ /usr/bin/python36
-bash: /usr/bin/python36: No such file or directory

Comment: $ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3

Comment: Do you use conda?

Comment: Never heard of conda.

Comment: I assume that you use `which python3` in the normal, non-environment directory?

Comment: Yes, it was deactivated at the moment

Comment: And this file is not a symlink? `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3`

Comment: OMG, this actually reports 3.7 as a version $ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 03:13:28) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: It is even weirder and more disgusting than I thought

Comment: :| "+" will be sufficient award for debugging your problem for me ;D

Comment: Why is there a simlink to 3.7? I used a normal installer.... Please explain and put it in your answer so I can accept it. I can't accept an answer written in a comment :)

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the accepted answer, be also aware that changing the directory name where your venv is located causes using the default python and pip paths of your system, instead of using the venv one.

Answer (score -1):

The Python version is different from the virtualenv python version and that is why it is complaining.
You can recreate your virtual environment(delete the existing one) and use the following command

virtualenv --python=`your python version here` venv
Or

mkvirtualenv venv --python=`your python version here`

if you want to create your virtual environment using mkvirtualenv command.

Comment: I don't use virtualenv. I use 'python3 -m venv'.