# How to create a Virtualenv with Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I have a problem with Linux in PC. I installed python3.8. I want work with python 3. When I create a virtualenv file it gets created with python2, but I don't want work with python2. How can I enable python2?

Comment: can you post the code you're using to create the virtualenv?

Comment: Type **python3** instead of **python** while executing commands.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Python 3 in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842713/using-python-3-in-virtualenv)

Comment: virtualenv file name

Comment: Is there a typo in "How can I enable python2?", you do _not_ want to run any python2 in this venv. You want a python3.x interpreter

Answer (score 5):

You can set a python version while creating a new virtual environment using the `-p` flag.

```
virtualenv -p python3.8 my-env-name
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try to locate the location of the python version you want to use the interpreter of (eg. get its path through `which python3`). Once obtained the path you can create the enviroment specifying the location of the interpreter you want to use for that virtual environment `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.6 venv`