# Requirement is installed but when I try to run the program it says it doesn't

Tags: python, django, migrate, requirements

Like the title says, I install crispy forms and it's installed, but when I try to migrate, it says crispy forms it's not installed

```
(env) C:\Users\Dias\Desktop\Soccer_site\aposta_segura>pip3 install django-crispy-forms
Requirement already satisfied: django-crispy-forms in c:\users\dias\desktop\soccer_site\aposta_segura\env\lib\site-packages (1.9.0)

(env) C:\Users\Dias\Desktop\Soccer_site\aposta_segura>python3 manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Dias\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", lin
e 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Dias\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", lin
e 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Dias\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Dias\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in po
pulate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Dias\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in crea
te
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_forms'

(env) C:\Users\Dias\Desktop\Soccer_site\aposta_segura>
```

If I install using the requirements.txt, the same thing happens, it says all the requirements are installed but crispy forms is not, i tried using "--user" but it doesn't work, don't know if it's a windows thing

Comment: You have already activated your virtual env, you should probably use `python manage.py migrate`. `python3` is not resolving to the python interpreter in your virtual env. You can test this by running `where python3` and `where python`, the result that is located within your virtual env is the correct one to use

Comment: Thye both appear in the same directory
`C:\Users\Dias>where python
C:\Users\Dias\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

C:\Users\Dias>where python3
C:\Users\Dias\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe`

using just python worked, will I have any sort of problems though,since I'm using an "older version"?

Comment: `python worked` this means that `python` is configured for your venv. `will I have any sort of problems though,since I'm using an "older version"?` this depends on what you are trying to do. You can always set a venv for python3 see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842713/using-python-3-in-virtualenv)

Answer (score 2):

As @lain mentioned, it seems that the `Requirement is already satisfied` in your venv. This could only mean that the interpreter cannot be resolved to the correct venv.

check this in cmd prompt

```
where python
```

And

```
where python3
```

The output of the first will match to the same directory as your `venv`.

Most likely its `python` so just use `python manage.py migrate` and it should work.