# NLTK tokenization output not visible

Tags: python, python-3.x, output, nltk

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
print("Test by SG")
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
lines = 'I was running around in the road then saw a bus'
is_noun = lambda pos:pos[:2] == 'NN'
tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize(lines)
nouns = [word for (word, pos) in nltk.pos_tag(tokenized) if is_noun(pos)] 
print (nouns)
```

I am only getting output:

```
Test by SG Content-Type: text/html
```

but the output should be:

```
['road', 'bus']
```

I am not getting the correct output.

Comment: Are you running this code in interpreter (command line) or Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 0):

Working fine in both Notebook and python console. The problem may be in you NLTK package installation. Please use [virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842713/using-python-3-in-virtualenv) if not and install nltk package, download the nltk-data . Must check the nltk-data download location for confirmation.
The download location will be looked like:

```
[nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Unzipping tokenizers\punkt.zip.
[nltk_data] Downloading package averaged_perceptron_tagger to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Unzipping taggers\averaged_perceptron_tagger.zip.
```

If you are a windows user.