# pip install on Jupyter kerner venv (virtual environment) is not updated

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-venv

I'm creating the Jupyter kernel within the virtual environment but the pkg in Juypter notebook is still missing after pip install

Answer (score 0):

First create your virtual env using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54183964/1340604) and activate it!

Create the kernel using:

```
ipython kernel install --name=gen-py3
```

Now the kernel details would be in:

```
/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/gen-py3
```

note: you can cd to this folder and open the file `kernel.json` and see the details of your env, for example mine is:

```
 "argv": [
  "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "gen-py3",
 "language": "python"
```

Which means is taken out of the global Python env b/c of this  `"/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7"`
In some cases when you're running in your venv it's constantly taken out of you global env and not your venv. Not try to run in your venv:

```
virtualenv -p python3 venv
source <env_name>/bin/activate ; in our case venv
pip install ipython
pip install ipykernel
```

and make sure you run

```
ipython kernel install --name=venv-test
```

from your venv ipython.
for example if your virtual env is venv and the location is

```
~/venv
```

run:

```
/Users/nathanielkohn/venv/bin/ipython kernel install --name=venv-test
```

Now open the kernel.json file, find the location by running:

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

And your kernel.json file is with the venv:

```
{
 "argv": [
  "/Users/<your_user_name>/venv/bin/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "venv-test",
 "language": "python",
 "metadata": {
  "debugger": true
 }
```