# How can I find out what different versions of Python installed on OSX?

Tags: python

It looks like there is more than one Python installed on my mac. 
Modules installed are not recognized by python interpreter (2.7.6) until I add them to PYTHONPATH.

Could anyone show me how I can locate all the Pythons installed on my mac?

Thank you

Comment: use `which -a python` to list all python installs

Answer (score 0):

As per [python location on mac osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819661/python-location-on-mac-osx), running the command by the user asking the question should give you any locations python is installed to. If this command returns multiple locations, you can follow the steps in the chosen answer to get the versions.

Answer (score 0):

The article below might be helpful. It might give you an idea.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-python-version/

Answer (score 0):

you can use `which python` command to find what python you are using. This gives the output as path to symlink, you can find the original python by reading the symlink.