# Mutliple Python installs necessary?

Tags: python

So I've read this thread
[python location on mac osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819661/python-location-on-mac-osx)

but still a couple questions

running

```
$ which -a python python3
```

returns

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

and just

```
$which python
```

returns

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

And I also have Python installed here which isn't on my PATH

```
/Users/foo/Library/Python/2.7/bin
```

Does this mean I can safely delete ALL python binaries except for the one returned by the which Python command?
I just don't understand the necessity of multiple Python installs if you don't need multiple versions.

Comment: Why do you need to delete the binaries? It's a way to problems with your installation.

Comment: Note that those "extra installs" might just be symlinks to a single "real" install.

Answer (score 2):

**Do not** delete the default python installation that comes with the OS, you will break your system, that Pythons are necessary for the right functionality of the OS, don't mess with them, if you want to develop your own projects, better use `pyenv` (https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) or similar tools to manage independent Python installations and/or versions, also to manage a virtual environment.

Never touch pre-installed binaries, unless you want to break your system.