# How to fix errors when doing a git commit?

Tags: python, git

I am currently trying to do a simple git commit -m "first commit" but it is not working

whenever i run this command:

```
 git commit -m "first commit"
```

I get this error:

```
env: python3.7: Not a directory
```

My first attempt was to do brew upgrade python
This pointed python3 to python@3.8.
I ran the git command again but I am still have the same issue.
if i have upgraded to python3.8 why is my terminal still giving me the error:

```
env: python3.7: Not a directory
```

My second attempt was to check the environment variable by running the env command
but i do not see any environment variable set to python3.7

After reading [python location on mac osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819661/python-location-on-mac-osx)
My third attempt was to create a symbol link to python3.7.
so i did

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/bin/python3.7 
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/bin/python3.7-config /usr/local/bin/python3.7-config
```

After this i tested by running a git commit command. The result was

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".git/hooks/pre-commit", line 44, in <module>
    os.execvp(CMD[0], CMD)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/bin/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 574, in execvp
    _execvpe(file, args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/bin/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 616, in _execvpe
    raise last_exc
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/bin/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 607, in _execvpe
    exec_func(fullname, *argrest)
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory
```

Please can you help me to resolve this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File ".git/hooks/pre-commit", line 44, in <module>
> ```

You've installed a bad pre-commit hook.