# I can't locate my python path (but able to locate python3 path)

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, version

I'm currently using Mac Pro and downloaded python through `brew install python` for the latest version (though it downloaded 3.9.12 instead of 3.10.x).

Also, while playing with the command lines, I also installed `pyenv` (version 2.2.5).

The problem is, I am now unable to get the default python version.
The command `python --version` and `python -h` all gives me `zsh: command not found: python`.

However, when I do `python3 --version`, it gives me `Python 3.9.12`.

Did I mess things up? Is there are way to go back to the state before I altered anything? (or at least recover my default `python` version?)

Comment: `/usr/bin/python3`, you can use `whereis python3` to know it's location

Comment: II'm actually trying to look for the default python rather than python3.. Is there a way? The `whereis python` just gives me the result of `python:`

Comment: this may help [python-location-on-mac-osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819661/python-location-on-mac-osx)

Comment: hmm.. I'm not being able to get the specific answer I wish to get... Would this mean that I am unable to recover the default python of the macos? (which I remember is the python 2 version)

Comment: Are you sure you have Python2 installed to begin with? I'm writing from a Mac pro as well, and I'm getting the same results as you are.

Comment: really? I guess then this is normal? Cos when I started my python right after I bought Mac pro, I got the results that it had a default python of version 2.7.x.
After installing python 3.x.x, the `python --version` disappeared and only the `python3 --version` is showing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python location on mac osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819661/python-location-on-mac-osx)

Comment: I was recommended this page earlier, but it doesn't really answer my question... 
I'm currently actually guessing that either the default python version was deleted from the mac pro somehow while I was fidgeting around :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of MacOS are you running? Starting in 12.3, Python2 was removed from the system.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-12_3-release-notes

Python
Deprecations
Python 2.7 was removed from macOS in this update. Developers should use Python 3 or an alternative language instead. (39795874)